# Passing datatable to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a datatable created in C#.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    dt.Columns.Add("MetricId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Descr", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("EntryDE", typeof(int));
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[0].Value);
    }

    // TODO: pass dt
}
```

And I have a stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin_Fill] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@MetricId INT,
@Descr VARCHAR(100),
@EntryDE VARCHAR(20)
```

What I want is to pass the datatable to this stored procedure, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a Table Valued Parameter as of SQL Server 2008 / .NET 3.5....

Check out [the guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Also, as there other options available, I have a comparisonof 3 approaches of passing multiple values (single field) to a sproc ([TVP vs XML vs CSV](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html))

Comment: Do I have to create a table type and define the structure in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, need to create a new table type

Answer (score 10):

1. You need to define a Table Type that you want to pass in **User-Defined Table Types** in your database.
2. Then you need to add the parameter in your Stored Procedure to pass it in like this:

   ```sql
   @YourCustomTable AS [dbo].YourCustomTable Readonly,
   ```
3. Then, when you have your rows setup, call it like this:

   ```cs
   // Setup SP and Parameters
   command.CommandText = "YOUR STORED PROC NAME";
   command.Parameters.Clear();
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someIdForParameter", someId);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourCustomTable",dtCustomerFields).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

   //Execute
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```

This should resolve your problem

Comment: That's right if we create Table-Valued Parameter Types as @AdaTheDev linked.

eg:
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE
    ( CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50) )

Comment: I had to set the parameter's TypeName property as well. That meant I couldn't use the AddWithValue method. But this answer got me on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

We generally squirt the data into XML documents and pass the data to the database as an NTEXT parameter.