# How to get different member of a datasource from Listbox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#

I have a listbox on a winform that is bound to a datasource with 5 fields on it.
ID,
Dbase,
Schema,
Table,
Security_Groups

The listbox DisplayMember is Table and the ValueMember is ID

Based on the selection made in the list box, I would like to return Dbase and Schema to variables.
Can anyone please advise how this can be achieved?

```
            Table = Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem);
            Dbase = Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem);
            Schema = Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem);
```

Many thanks,
Dave

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 



namespace Reference_Table_Updater
{



    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
    DataTable dt;
    String ComboString;
    String Dbase;
    String Schema;
    String strConnection =  "server=uk;" +
    "Database='Scratchpad';" +
    "Integrated Security=SSPI";
        public FrmMain()
        {


        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;

        }

        //public class DataSource_Items
        //{
        //    public Int16 Key { get; set;}
        //    public String Table { get; set; }
        //    public String Schema { get; set; }
        //    public String Dbase { get; set; }

        //}

            public void BindGridView(string field)
            {


            dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            try
            {
            connection.Open();

            ComboString = Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem);
            Schema = ((FrmMain)Tbl_List.SelectedItem).Schema;
            Dbase = ((FrmMain)Tbl_List.SelectedItem).Dbase;

            MessageBox.Show(Dbase + "." + Schema + "." + ComboString);


            string sqlStatement = "Select * from " + ComboString;
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", field);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }
            else
            {
            // NO RECORDS FOUND
            }
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
            string msg = "Fetch Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
            connection.Close();
            }
            }



            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            this.updateable_TablesTableAdapter.Fill(this.scratchpadDataSet.Updateable_Tables);
            BindGridView(Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem));

            }


            private void Tbl_List_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            if (Tbl_List.SelectedValue != null)
            {
            BindGridView(Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem));

            }

            }

            private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            //PASS INSERT/UPDATE/DELETES TO SQL SERVER HERE Passing datatable to a stored procedure if possible  - 
                //I like the TVP option
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320594/passing-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure

            BindGridView(Tbl_List.GetItemText(Tbl_List.SelectedItem));
            }



            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                FrmAbout F2 = new FrmAbout();
                F2.ShowDialog();

            }






    }


}
```

Comment: `Dbase = ((YourClass)Tbl_List.SelectedItem).Dbase;`?

Comment: Ok that makes sense but being so new to C# I am getting confused. I don't have a class for the datasource as its not defined programmatically. I added the code above to see if it makes sense.

Comment: Nothing in your code shows how you set the DataSource of `Tbl_List`.

Comment: Its set in the databinding section of the properties window for Tbl_List.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figured it out eventually:

Declared:

```
 DataRowView d1;
 String Dbase;
 String Schema;
```

Set:

```
d1 = Tbl_List.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
```

Set:

```
Dbase = d1["Database"].ToString();
Schema = d1["Schema"].ToString();
```

Punched Dbase and Schema out to two temp text boxes on the form to prove it worked:

```
this.TBDbase.Text = Dbase;
this.TBSchema.Text = Schema;
```

Cheers all,
Dave