# Converting List to Datatable to be passed a table type in Stored proc

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a Web API call where I'm sending a list of objects to a stored proc. I am creating a datatable to be sent to my stored proc however when I try to add to my datatable it returns back a 500 status right away.

```
    private static DataTable CreateTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Project_Name", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Project_Staffing_Period", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Employment_Start_Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Employment_Rate_Type_Code", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Employment_Rate_Effective_Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Company_ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Person_ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Project_Role_Type_Code", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Staffed_Hours", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("CreateID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("CreateTS", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("UpdateID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("UpdateTS", typeof(DateTime));
        return dt;
    }
```

This is my DataTable format.

```
    public class ProjectStaffing
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProjectStaffingPeriod { get; set; }
        public DateTime EmploymentStartDate { get; set; }
        public string EmploymentRateTypeCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime EmploymentRateEffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectRoleTypeCode { get; set; }
        public decimal StaffedHours { get;set; }
        public string CreateID { get; set; }
        public string UpdateID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateTS { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateTS { get; set; }
```

Here is my class format

```
        public async Task<string> CreateProjectStaffingByDateRange(List<ProjectStaffing> projectstaffings)
        {
            string statusMessage;
            DataTable dt = CreateTable();

            for(int i = 0; i < projectstaffings.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(projectstaffings[i].ProjectName, projectstaffings[i].ProjectStaffingPeriod, 
                    projectstaffings[i].EmploymentStartDate, projectstaffings[i].EmploymentRateTypeCode, 
                    projectstaffings[i].EmploymentRateEffectiveDate, projectstaffings[i].CompanyID, 
                    projectstaffings[i].PersonID, projectstaffings[i].ProjectRoleTypeCode, projectstaffings[i].StaffedHours, 
                    projectstaffings[i].CreateID, projectstaffings[i].CreateTS, projectstaffings[i].UpdateID, projectstaffings[i].UpdateTS);
            }

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlParameter returnValue; //Holds the bit that determines if insert was successful or not
                SqlCommand command;
                returnValue = new SqlParameter();
                command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "USP_Add_Project_Staffing_By_Date_Range";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempTable", dt);

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@statusMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                statusMessage = command.Parameters["@statusMessage"].Value.ToString().Trim();
            }
            return statusMessage;
        }
```

This is my call to the server. and where I add the rows to my datatable is where it fails and returns a 500 status.

Am I inserting into my datatable incorrectly? I matched the datatypes. I have check the ordering that I am inserting. All the values are not null.

Some sample values could be

```
ProjectName: "Project 1"
ProjectStaffingPeriod: "Oct 4, 2019"
EmploymentStartDate: "Oct 4, 2019"
EmploymentRateTypeCode: "NA Rate"
EmploymentRateEffectiveDate: "Oct 4, 2019"
CompanyID: 1
PersonID: 1
ProjectRoleTypeCode: "BA"
StaffedHours: 8.0
CreateID: "person1"
UpdateID: "person1"
CreateTS: "Oct 4, 2019 11:00 AM"
UpdateTS: "Oct 4, 2019 11:00 AM"
```

Comment: If you wrap it in a `try/catch` you could add a breakpoint and find out what is throwing the 500, meaning, actually capture the exception being thrown. One thing I would add is not to use `AddWithValue`, actually specify that the parameter type is `SqlDbType.Structured`, that may save some headache once you get passed the adding rows issue.

Comment: Have you set up the SP to receieve a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320594/passing-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure)?

Comment: In addition to @SimonWilson's suggestion to specify `SqlDbType.Structured`, avoid [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the rest of your set up but you seem to add the column  project name as an int to the datatable

```
    dt.Columns.Add("Project_Name", typeof(int));
```

but it is a String in your class

```
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Missed yet another simple mistake thanks for catching what my blind eyes couldnt